# Java - Iterate over an odd length String, two consecutive characters at once

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, stringindexoutofbounds

I was reading a file(using BufferedReader & FileReader) line by line and needed to get two successive characters & store it in two distinct variables for every iteration of the loop, but the String lengths can be either 'even' or 'odd'.

In case of 'even' length Strings, a simple 'even' check would do it, as follows:

```
if (line.length() % 2 == 0) {
    char firstChar = line.charAt(i);
    char secondChar = line.charAt(i + 1);
}
```

But for 'odd' length Strings, couldn't find a better approach other than the one below-

I tried the following for both 'even' and 'odd' length Strings:

```
public void readTwoChars(BufferedReader b) {

    String line = null;
    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i += 2){
            char firstChar = line.charAt(i);
            char secondChar = 0;
            if (i != line.length() - 1) {
                secondChar = line.charAt(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Is there a better way to iterate through an Array/String and get two elements/characters at once for both even and odd length Strings/Arrays ?,** would love to learn more.

Comment: The last code snippet can already handle both even and odd length strings. What do you not like about it? How do you want to improve it?

Comment: Looking for some kind of Iterator based approaches if any as I am not too familiar with it, might help me learn

Comment: `String` doesn't have an iterator. It is not `Iterable`. You can write your own iterator for `String`, but I think that's overkill.

Comment: I suppose you have to do something with your two chars?

Comment: you can also change the condition of the loop to `i < line.length()-1` and handle the last character after the loop, avoiding the `if` inside the loop -- depending on what you have to do, eventually even handle the first character before the loop, and iterate starting with `i = 1` -- but you did not explain what is being done, specially with the *extra* character in the odd length case

Comment: @Sweeper technically there is an iterator for `String`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/StringCharacterIterator.html

Comment: @Sweeper well you can use `for(int ch: (Iterable<Integer>)() -> string.chars() .iterator()) { … }` but the actual question is, how does the OP think, can a one-at-time iterator solve this two-at-a-time problem better than the already existing code.

Comment: What is the integrity of having even and odd indices?  Maybe there is another way to code it.

Answer (score 0):

Your below code snippet is already quite reasonable and I don't think there would be any better solution but you can make it look cleaner by doing the following -

```
public void readTwoChars(BufferedReader b) {

    String line = null;
    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
        int length = line.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
            char firstChar = line.charAt(i);
            char secondChar = (i + 1 < length) ? line.charAt(i + 1) : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alter your `for` loop to beginning at `i = 1` and just take the `char` pairs `(i - 1, i)` as long as `i` is less than the length of the input `String` (the line in your case):

```
public void readTwoChars(BufferedReader b) {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
        // start at 1 and use a simple increment
        for (int i = 1; i < line.length(); i++) {
            // then just take the pair
            char firstChar = line.charAt(i - 1);
            char secondChar = line.charAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```